# Postgres replication: Should I use built-in mechanis or have the middleware control it?

Tags: java, postgresql, replication

For a pet project of mine (that has grown beyond expectations) I need to add some form of load-balancing and failure-safety. The project uses three layers:

1. Frontend (that the customers access)
2. Middleware (provides communication between frontend and backend)
3. Backend (business logic, data storage)

The middleware is a Java servlet, the backend is PostgreSQL. There is one database for each customer, so there are DBs coming and going the entire time. The backend is pretty simple as new data is imported once every 24h and the rest of the time it is basically read-only.

To make the whole system more resilient (to server failures, load spikes etc) I now want to replicate the backend onto other servers. The middleware can then evenly distribute the requests to all running backends.

Now the question is how to approach the replication:

1. Let the middleware do all the work (make a DB dump, push that dump to the other backend servers and restore it)
2. Use Postgres' built-in mechanisms  (Slony, Streaming Repliation etc.)

Both ways have their pros and cons and neither feels completely right. My main thoughts are:

- Using the middleware will provide greater control, I can more easily determine which customers currently exist and replicate those DBs only. It will be easier to add new backend servers to the cluster. I can do the replication on-demand, ie. when the new data for this customer has been imported. There is quite a bit of development work involved to correctly handle pg_dump and pg_restore
- Using the built-in mechanisms will save some work and will likely perform better and more reliable. I need to provide some communication channel between the backend servers (SSH, VPN).

So, what's the better approach here? I tend to like the middleware option but that just might be my very limited experience with Postgres.

Bonus question: If the Postgres replication is the better option, which mechanism (of which there are quite a few now in Postgres 9) is the best for my scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd agree with ocharles that there's not point in re-inventing the wheel here. However, if pg_dump/pg_restore can do it for you that's a perfectly good setup. The reason why a full dump/restore aren't usually viable for replication is:

1. Database is too large - a full dump/restore takes too long.
2. Database is too active - you need to keep the copy up to date.

If these aren't problems for you, then your replication process might just be:

For each database...

1. Insert "about to take backup at time T" to some logging table
2. pg_dump database
3. copy backup to one or more slaves
4. pg_restore
5. Check our timestamp insert from above is present in the slave

This is simple, maintainable and offers you a great bonus - daily, archivable, self-contained backups of each active database.

Of course, if your databases become too large, or need updating more than once a day then this is *not* going to work for you.

Comment: Richard, I really like the idea with the timestamp. Simple and effective!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, build on top of existing solutions. Replication is hard, and a lot of smart people have already done the bulk of the work. Slony, Londiste, Streaming Replication all give you different features, but the all have one thing in common: they do work. As to which you go with, that depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Streaming replication will give you multiple read-only nodes that are only very slightly behind the master node (usually not noticable). It will remove the admin overhead of applying schema changes, it's binary replication. However, it's all or nothing replication (replication at the cluster level). It's not particularly difficult to setup, providing you have root access to all servers.

Londiste/Slony will give you more control of what gets replicated, giving you control down to the table level. This can make it easy to add nodes that only do a single task - ie, one area of business - which may or may not be useful to you. Installation is a little more involved, and schema migrations are more complicated. With Londiste you get PGQ, so you now have a message queue in your database, which again - may or may not be useful for other parts of your business.

I have just set up binary streaming replication (a hot standby node) as our production database had a minor hiccup recently, so that's in place for failover. I've been so impressed by how it works though, and how up to date it is, we're also considering load balancing read only queries to this node. I've brief experience with Londiste and found it well documented, but I usually want entire cluster replication, so hot standby makes the most sense for me.

I don't see what you'll gain doing the replication yourself, other than wasting time/creating bugs/giving yourself more work than you need to.

Comment: There is no need for a slave to be (slightly) behind the master, that's a choice: Use synchronous or asynchronous replication, what fits best in your situation. Synchronous replication is slower because the master has to wait for it's slave(-s).

Comment: ocharles, thanks a lot for the overview! Streaming replication is not an option as I will will need more fine-grained control over which databases and tables to replicate. For that matter, how easy is it to programatically and dynamically configure Londiste / Slony to tell them which DBs / tables I want to replicate to which node?

Answer (score 0):

Answering the follow up question by OP -- Setting up / configuring Londiste is pretty simple. Just a few easy steps involved and then you can add arbitrary tables on master for replication and have them materialised on destination databases (with cascading replication available).  There are multiple how-to's in doc folder in skytools package describing different scenarios.